# Не заполняйте голову тем(,) что вам не интересно

Tags: пунктуация

Не заполняйте голову тем(,) что вам не интересно.

Answer (score 5):

Запятая нужна. Это классический случай сложноподчинённого предложения, где со слова "что" начинается придаточная часть.

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Запятая ставится.

СПП  местоименно-определительное (или местоименно-соотносительное), для него характерно наличие местоименной пары (тем - что, указательное слово - союзное слово).

Comment: Большое спасибо!